# The first radio button is unchecked while selecting the second one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have checkboxes and radio buttons on my page.

**I have some scenario.**

1. When the user selects the first checkbox then the first radio will select and if you unchecked the checkbox then the radio button will unchecked.
2. If the user directly selects the radio button then the nearest checkbox will select.

The above scenarios are almost working, I am getting the issue on the second checkbox.

I select the first checkbox then the first radio button is selected. If I select the second check then the radio button is selecting but the first radio is unchecked.

[image]
[image]

```js
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.reviewers-details').find('.selectRV').prop('checked', true);
});

$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).closest('.reviewers-details').find('.selectRV').prop('checked');


  if (checkbox == true) {
    // $(this).closest('.reviewers-details').find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
    $(this).closest('.reviewers-details').find('input[type=radio]:first').prop('checked', true);
  } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
    $(this).closest('.reviewers-details').find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="reviewers-details d-table sectionHeading">
  <div class="d-table-cell">
    <input type="checkbox" name="reviewerid[1]" class="revieweruser selectRV" value="1">test
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="reviewer_timeslot[1]" class="revieweruser" value="1">
        <label>abc</label>:
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="reviewer_timeslot[1]" class="revieweruser" value="3">
        <label>xyz</label>:

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="reviewers-details d-table sectionHeading">
  <div class="d-table-cell">
    <input type="checkbox" name="reviewerid[1]" class="revieweruser selectRV" value="1">demo
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="reviewer_timeslot[1]" class="revieweruser" value="1">
        <label>abc</label>:
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="reviewer_timeslot[1]" class="revieweruser" value="3">
        <label>xyz</label>:
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All **radio buttons with the same value for their `name` attribute** will be part of the same radio group: if one becomes selected, the others automatically become unselected.

Below, I simply renamed the radio buttons in your second group to isolate them (and their linked checkbox) from the first group.

(You may want to rename the checkbox as well, unless you have a reason for it to share a name with the first checkbox.)

```js
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
  $(this)
    .closest('.reviewers-details')
    .find('.selectRV')
    .prop('checked', true);
});

$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this)
    .closest('.reviewers-details')
    .find('.selectRV')
    .prop('checked');

  if (checkbox == true) {
    $(this)
      .closest('.reviewers-details')
      .find('input[type=radio]:first')
      .prop('checked', true);
  }
  else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
    $(this)
      .closest('.reviewers-details')
      .find('input[type=radio]')
      .prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="reviewers-details d-table sectionHeading">
  <div class="d-table-cell">
    <input type="checkbox"
      name="reviewerid[1]"
      class="revieweruser selectRV"
      value="1"
    />test
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="radio"
          name="reviewer_timeslot[1]"
          class="revieweruser"
          value="1"
        />
        <label>abc</label>:
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio"
          name="reviewer_timeslot[1]"
          class="revieweruser"
          value="3"
        />
        <label>xyz</label>:
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="reviewers-details d-table sectionHeading">
  <div class="d-table-cell">
    <input type="checkbox"
      name="reviewerid[1]"
      class="revieweruser selectRV"
      value="1"
    />demo
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="radio"
          name="reviewer_timeslot[2]"
          class="revieweruser"
          value="1"
        />
        <label>abc</label>:
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio"
          name="reviewer_timeslot[2]"
          class="revieweruser"
          value="3"
        />
        <label>xyz</label>:
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change the index number. I have to change from 1 to 2 in the second radio buttons. Thanks for the help.